# How to create good GCP datastore indexes?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a GCP datastore query in my code:

```
cls.query(
                ndb.OR(cls.is_miscategorized == True,
                       cls.is_category_recommendation_mismatched == True,
                       cls.is_class_recommendation_mismatched == True),
                cls.account_type == account_type,
                cls.transaction_date >= start_date,
                cls.transaction_date <= end_date,
            )
```

For which I have created this index:

```
- kind: Table name
  properties:
  - name: is_miscategorized
  - name: is_category_recommendation_mismatched
  - name: is_class_recommendation_mismatched
  - name: account_type
  - name: transaction_date
    direction: desc
```

As per my understanding of indexes, I have included all the expected fields in right order here. But I still get the error that Indexes are missing

```
no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: Table name
  properties:
  - name: account_type
  - name: is_class_recommendation_mismatched
  - name: transaction_date
    direction: desc
  - name: create_time
```

I have added the composite index suggested in the error message too. But I still get the same error, weirdly with the same suggested index in the error message.

Now I have two questions:

1. The indexes suggested by GCP seem wrong. They have fields missing. So how does GCP suggest indexes? Are they worth relying upon?
2. What am I doing wrong with indexes here? Why am I getting the error with my original index?

Comment: Newly added indexes take a little time to build. To check if your 'new' indexes are ready for use, go to console.cloud.google.com > Datastore > Indexes and you'll see a status of your indexes

Comment: @NoCommandLine, before triggering my query, I checked if the indexes are up and running or not.  The indexes were up and and running.

Comment: okay. The recommended index includes ```create_time```. The one you have doesn't include it

Answer (score 0):

NDB's implementation of OR does a separate query for each OR clause.  So you aren't doing one query to the backend, but 3.  E.g.

```
class.query(cls.is_miscategorized == True,
            cls.transaction_date >= start_date,
            cls.transaction_date <= end_date)
```

This query requires a composite index, and the other 2 queries require their own composite index.

Your recommended index has account_type & create_time, but that is not in your example. Did you leave those out?